# Homebrew with custom CFLAGS

Tags: homebrew

How do I compile some specific package with my custom CFLAGS? Other searches suggest that I should just edit the formula by hand but I don't want to do because I want a solution that easily works in all cases.

Or do they strictly not want to allow custom CFLAGS? [This](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/21173) suggests it.

Esp., in my case, I just want to pass one of `-mmacosx-version-min=10.6`, `-isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk`, `-DMAC_OS_X_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED=1060` or `--with-macos-sdk=/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk` to CFLAGS because I want to build a library which is compatible with >=MacOSX 10.6.

Comment: If you are to distribute the flags anyway, what about storing modified formula in a [tap](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/Interesting-Taps-%26-Branches)?

Comment: @Jokester: What do you mean by "distribute flags"? Also, what modified formula? I don't want to modify any formula.